# Airflow can't finish dag runs when the start date of a task is greater than the execution date

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to implement a DAG with multiple tasks having different start dates.
According to Airflow documentation is definitely something allowed but not sure if it is a right pattern.

Here a Dag example:

```
import datetime as dt
import os

from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.models import DAG, Variable


with DAG(DAG_ID, default_args={}, schedule_interval="0 4 * * *",) as dag:
    op1 = DummyOperator(start_date=dt.datetime(2019, 7, 1), task_id="op1", dag=dag,)

    op2 = DummyOperator(start_date=dt.datetime(2019, 7, 5), task_id="op2", dag=dag,)
```

The first dag run is scheduled for 2019-07-01, and op1 is executed without the problem, and as expected op2 is not executed. This is the behaviour I am expecting.
However, the scheduler is not able to move to the next dag run on 2019-07-02, since the previous dag run (on 2019-07-01) is still under the running status.

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour, and automatically set the dag run to complete, when all the tasks with `start_date < execution_date` are completed?

I am running airflow 1.10.2 (but from some simple test, nothing changes moving to the latest version).

Answer (score 0):

The above dag comprises of both op1 and op2, which differ in `start_date`.

Looks like what you want to do is:

- op1 should run daily at 04:00 from 2019-07-01 onwards.
- op2 should run daily at 04:00 from 2019-07-05 onwards.

I would suggest

- to either have **two separate dags**.
- or make their `start_date` same.

If you do not want to go with these two approaches, then there is a parameter for dag called `max_active_runs` which can be increased as per your purpose. Read more [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html).

Comment: I haven't included in the example, but the two operators should have some dependency. `op1 >> op2`.

Using the same start_date is an option, but then you need some logic for managing op2 when there are no data.

The max_active_runs does not solve the problem, it just starts more dag runs, but none of them can be completed.

Comment: [ExternalTaskSensor](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-engineering-how-to-set-dependencies-between-data-pipelines-in-apache-airflow-using-sensors-fc34cfa55fba), hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Shiv, it is what I am trying to avoid. I have too many dependencies and tracking them with the ExternalTaskSensor is a nightmare.
I am actually moving away from having 1 task per dag and many ExternalTaskSensors for managing the dependencies to a monolithic dag containing all the connected tasks.